# invalid signature error for edit product and new product form submission rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am currently working on a web marketplace app for an assignment that allows users to upload items for sale with images attached, and to edit those listings.

Currently i have utilised simple forms for the edit and add product pages and those work fine but when I click update or add product I get the below error:

```
    ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature in ProductsController#create
```

the error pointed out that line 3 of the below code is the problem:

```
       def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: "Product was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My product.rb file looks as such:

```
    belongs_to :user, :optional => true
    has_one_attached :picture
end
```

The simple forms work but for reference the form html looks like such:

```
<%= simple_form_for@product do |f| %>
    <h1 class="heading">Edit Product</h1>
    <%= render 'form', product: @product %>
<% end %>
```

Any help I can get would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `respond_to do |format|` method, you need to supply the actual formats that the code should respond to. So, your controller probably needs to look something like this:

```rb
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  @product.user_id = current_user.id
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      if @product.save
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

But I'd also ask: why are you using `respond_to` here if you only expect to process the result of a web form? It's something you may need to do at some point, but isn't required initially and adds complication.

If that doesn't resolve the issue, we'll probably need to see your strong-params function (`product_params`), the Product model definition and your view, at least. For example, you may need to structure the line more like this, because your params may well not exactly match the fields in your model.

```rb
  @product = Product.new(id: product_params[:id], name: product_params[:name])
```

Rails adds a special authentication code when it creates a form, to help stop bad actors from spamming or hacking your form. If your page is changed after the code is created, it will become out of date and be rejected, but I'd expect a more specific error if that was happening. Fingers crossed!